# Let's get critical: May 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Martial Arts Stack Exchange](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 7 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What can I practice to remove tension from my movements](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/1835/what-can-i-practice-to-remove-tension-from-my-movements)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Training while exhausted](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/1838/training-while-exhausted)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Are there any benefits to Sitting Seiza?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/1843/are-there-any-benefits-to-sitting-seiza)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Measuring the foot when buying Tabi (and giving the size using the japanese convention)](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/1862/measuring-the-foot-when-buying-tabi-and-giving-the-size-using-the-japanese-conv)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Impact of being smaller(shorter arms) and how to overcome this](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/1874/impact-of-being-smallershorter-arms-and-how-to-overcome-this)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [What is Fa-jin?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/1878/what-is-fa-jin)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 4)
- [Mawashi Gheri Vs Dollyo Chagi](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/1853/mawashi-gheri-vs-dollyo-chagi)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

Comment: This... is disappointing.